# Using htaccess to redirect to certain extension

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I want to know how to use `.htaccess` to redirect a certain path to a certain extension. To be more clear, I want to redirect something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/api/some/page
```

To this:

```
http://www.example.com/some/page.json
```

I understand that I could just do this using the router that is supplied by CakePHP, however, how would this be done with a `.htaccess` file?

Comment: So you want `/api/anything/here` to `/api/anything/here.json` ?

Comment: Yes it is possible but is there a deeper reason that you're wanting to append the json file extension to the page url? Are you already rewriting to `http://www.example.com/api/some/page`, if yes please show the code, if no then is this routed and if so using what?

Comment: @anubhava: No, the /api bit should be dropped. So `/api/anything/here` should go to `/anything/here.json`

Comment: @CraigvanTonder I am using [CakePHP](https://cakephp.org/) so the routing is handled by their `Router` class. I can probably do it using the router, but was hoping `.htaccess` can handle this for me.

Comment: Try adding `RewriteRule ^api/(?!.+\.json$)(.+)$ $1.json [L,NC]` just below `RewriteEngine On`

Comment: @anubhava That will just append .json to the existing url whereas he wants to drop /api from the url and then append .json onto it, right or am I confused?

Comment: My suggested rule does drop `api/` from target and adds `.json` in the end.

Comment: @anubhava Okay thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @CraigvanTonder you are indeed correct. I'm going to give the suggestion a go.

Comment: @anubhava: thanks. That's excellent. Please could you add it as an answer

Comment: @Albert revise your question as it's not an answer to it in the current state, you asked if it is possible, a simple yes would suffice.

Comment: Also, @anubhava, if you don't mind, could you give a short explanation of what each part of the rule does? I would just like to understand the answer instead of just copy/paste

Comment: @CraigvanTonder how's that edit, my compatriot? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To handle this rewrite, you may use this rule just below `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^api/(?!.+\.json$)(.+)$ $1.json [L,NC]
```

- `(?!.+\.json$)` is a negative lookahead that skips matching URIs that end with `.json` (to avoid a rewrite loop)
- Pattern `^api/(?!.+\.json$)(.+)$` matches URIs that start with `/api/` and captures part after `/api` in `$1`
- `$1.json` in target adds `.json` at the end of matched part
- **Flags:** `L` is for Last and `NC` is Ignore case

Comment: If you don't mind, could you give a short explanation of what each part of the rule does? I would just like to understand the answer instead of just copy/paste

Comment: Yes I've added detailed explanation in answer.

Comment: @anubhava absolute legend. Thanks